# Custom event to detect change of value in data tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-dataset

I have a div with a form in it that has a data tag that i have named `data-av`

I am appending the div as follows

```
> $("#desti_div").append("<div class='tmar"+count+"'><div
> class='form-group col-md-6 getspace'><label><i class='gicon fas
> fa-circle'></i> New Destination</label><input class='form-control
> input-lg form-field very_form' type='text' id='added_dest"+count+"'
> data-av='' name='added_dest' placeholder='New Destinaton' required><a
> href='' class='gored'><span
> class='form-control-feedback'></span>Delete</a></div><br/></div>");
```

I would like to fire an event every time the value of `data-av` changes. The id of the input that has the `data-av` has the id `id='added_dest"+count+"'` as shown in the code above so i should target the input with that id.

I am thinking of this

```
$('#someID').data("key", "newValue").trigger('changeData'); 

$('#someID').on('changeData', function (e) {    
    alert('My Custom Event - Change Data Called! for ' + this.id);
});
```

How can i watch if `newValue` changes so that i am able to show the custom event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Attribute selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). Also trigger the event after defining the *changeData* event handler function:

```js
$("#desti_div").append(`<div class='tmar"+count+"'><div
 class='form-group col-md-6 getspace'><label><i class='gicon fas
 fa-circle'></i> New Destination</label><input class='form-control
 input-lg form-field very_form' type='text' id='added_dest"+count+"'
 data-av='' name='added_dest' placeholder='New Destinaton' required><a
 href='' class='gored'><span
 class='form-control-feedback'></span>Delete</a></div><br/></div>`);

$('[data-av]').on('changeData', function (e) {    
    alert('My Custom Event - Change Data Called! for ' + this.id);
});
$('[data-av]').data("av", "newValue").trigger('changeData');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="desti_div"></div>
```